# Preventing overlap of multiple fixed positioned elements

Tags: html, css

if I have two divs on my page.  One has fixed positioning at the top of the page `style="position:fixed; left:0; top:0;right:0;"` and one has fixed positioning to the left of the page `style="position:fixed; left:0; top:0;bottom:0;"`  is there any way to have the left div positioned so it's top edge lines up with the bottom edge of the top positioned div without hard coding margins or padding?  By default there will be some partial overlap

Answer (score 0):

Placing both the `div` in another container `div` and defining the `position:fixed` style to the container `div` would solve your issue.

```
<div style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0;">
  <div>div 1</div>
  <div>div 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.div0{
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: blue;
  perspective: 100px;
}

.div1{
 position:fixed; left:0; top:0;right:0;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: red;

}

.div2{
 position:fixed; left:200; bottom:0;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="div0">
<div class="div1">div1</div>
<div class="div2">div2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think you want to do the same.

```css
.parent{
position: relative;
background-color: #000;
width: 600px;
height: 400px;
}
.child1,.child2{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
background-color: #f00;
height: 190px;
}
.child1{
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
.child2{
bottom: 0;
width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child1"></div>
<div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the top div has a defined `height`, you can simply take that value and use if for the left DIVs `top` setting:

```css
.top,
.left {
  position: fixed;
}

.top {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.left {
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
```